# IList clear not work as expected (null items)

Tags: c#, list

In my `IList myList = new List<someType>();` are let's say 3 items and if I call `myList.Clear();` there are still 3 `null` elements present!

Getter/Setter:

```
public IList MyList
{
    get { return myList ; }
    set { myList = value; }
}
```

So I want to clear and remove all items from the IList! How can I do this?

Comment: Show the relevant code where you are clearing the list, and how you verified that there are still items in the list after clearing it.

Comment: Maybe you've written a custom 'clear()' extension method instead of using 'Clear()'?

Comment: I just called MyList.Clear(); (as mentioned in the question) Verified it with the Visual Studio Debugger -> shows three null elements!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. This could happen if, for example, your `IList` is really an array and you are swallowing exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss to notice something, or not using the debugger properly to watch the object. There is nothing wrong with `.Clear()` its works properly and Removes all items from the IList. Here is a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uv3Fdr) for you:

```
public class sampleClass{

    private IList myList;

    public IList MyList
    {
       get { return myList ; }
       set { myList = value; }
    }
}

// Usage
sampleClass objClass = new sampleClass();
objClass.MyList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
Console.WriteLine(objClass.MyList.Count); // Will print 3
Console.WriteLine(objClass.MyList[0]); // will print A
objClass.MyList.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(objClass.MyList.Count); // Will print 0
Console.WriteLine(objClass.MyList[0]); // will throw Index was out of range Exception
```

This is based on the available information in your post, If you add more relevant code means I can explain things according to that.

Comment: Thx! Yes I know. Maybe something is wrong with our framework!

Comment: @leon22 - Can you please provide a [mcve] in your question?

Comment: @leon22: Can you please share your code and the framework details if possible?

Comment: It's not possible! (huge and confidential) But thank you for the clarification! I thought I was crazy ;-)

Comment: @leon22 In that case please delete your question, since without some code there isn't anything we can do to help. _The bug is in your code, and if you can't share the code (preferably a [mcve]) with us we can't help._

Comment: @mjwills I would but the system blocks the deletion!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation carefully you will find the answer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx

> Count is set to 0, and references to other objects from elements of the collection are also released.
>   Capacity remains unchanged. To reset the capacity of the List, call the TrimExcess method or set the Capacity property directly. Decreasing the capacity reallocates memory and copies all the elements in the List. Trimming an empty List sets the capacity of the List to the default capacity.

So you either have to cast it to a `List` or you have to agree to the fact that this is normal behaviour.

Comment: It's an IList not a List! So no TrimExcess available!

Comment: I doubt this is relevant since the OP claims there are still 3 elements in list despite calling `Clear()`. I doubt this is in any way related to the list's capacity, and is simply an error in his own code (which he did not provide).

Comment: @leon22: I agree, this method is only on the concrete implementation. But the concrete implementation is a `List` and he is calling `.Clear` which is in fact implemented like I stated and like the documentation is stated. The capacity remains 3.( see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.clear(v=vs.110).aspx)